# How do I return lets say 100 distinct ticket Id data from a view which returns two records per ticket Id using pagination?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view that returns two columns **Ticket_Id** and **Price**. Each ticket can have up to 2 different prices. Along with this, I have a stored procedure that returns the data from the view to the caller based on input parameters for pagination.

```
@page     : indicates the page number
@pageSize : indicates the number of records per page.
```

When a user requests 100 (unique tickets)rows I will have to return at most 200 rows of data.
For which i am using pagination as follows

`OFFSET ', @pageSize,' * (',@page,' - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT ', @pageSize,' ROWS ONLY`

But it returns only 100 rows of data including duplicates. Is there a way I can modify the pagination parameters to retrieve all 200 rows of data ?

Example :
view returns as follows :

| ticket_id | price |
| --- | --- |
| ticket1 | 10 |
| ticket1 | 12 |
| ticket2 | 11 |
| ticket2 | 13 |
| ticket3 | 12 |
| ticket3 | 14 |

when the user requests with the input parameters:

```
@page = 1 , @PageSize = 3
```

I need to return all 6 rows of data.

**View(Using view because stored procedure dosent not have access to tickets table directly)**

```
select tck.ticket_id, tck.cost as 'price'
        --,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY tck.ticket_id) 'Rank'
                        
    from tickets tck with (NOLOCK)
```

Store procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_trans_history_srch]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @page   int=1,              --optional
    @pageSize   int=20          --optional
AS
BEGIN
    declare @finalsqlstmt nvarchar(max)
    declare @pageString nvarchar(max)
    declare @pageCount nvarchar(max) = ''
    declare @viewName nvarchar(max)

    set @pageString =concat(' OFFSET ', @pageSize,' * (',@page,' - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT ', @pageSize,' ROWS ONLY')

    set @finalsqlstmt = concat('select * from ',dbo.f_get_dbname(),@viewName,'where ',@search ,' and created_date between ''',@startDate,''' and ''',@endDate,''' order by created_date desc ',@pageString)

    set @pageCount =concat('select count(distinct ticket_id) from ',dbo.f_get_dbname(),@viewName,'where ',@search,' and created_date between ''',@startDate,''' and ''',@endDate,'''' )
    
    exec (@finalsqlstmt)
    exec (@pageCount)

END
```

**Note: I tried using `RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ticket_id) 'Rank'` and returning data based on rank, but because of the huge table size the performance of the query reduced drastically.**

Comment: Pagination using offsets is always slow, because with every data access the DBMS has to order all rows again from the beginning to get to the offset. This is why pagination is typically done with IDs instead. I.e. "give me the next 200 rows with IDs greater than ___". And as this is still rather slow, we often look for additional methods, like materialized views with numbered rows or a even a separate pagination table that would contain all page numbers and their min and max IDs.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So in this scenario, the best approach would be with numbered views?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry. I don't know enough about SQL Server to make a recommendation here. And this also depends on the table (frequency of inserts and deletes in particular). I hope others can point you to the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can get "100 rows" if you pivot your two prices into two columns (for example "A" and "B"). I don't know if this is an option in your situation but here is an example:

```
DECLARE @t6 TABLE (A VARCHAR(100), B INT)

INSERT INTO @t6 (A,B)
          SELECT 'ticket1',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'ticket1',12
UNION ALL SELECT 'ticket2',11
UNION ALL SELECT 'ticket2',13
UNION ALL SELECT 'ticket3',12
UNION ALL SELECT 'ticket3',14

;WITH cte_topivot AS
(
    SELECT 
        [A],
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY B ASC) = 1 
            THEN 'ticketA' ELSE 'ticketB' END [pivotCol],
        [B]
    FROM @t6 t
)
SELECT p.* 
FROM cte_toPivot tp
PIVOT(MIN(B) FOR pivotCol IN ([ticketA],[ticketB])) p
```

Otherwise, if you are always getting exactly half the rows you want, can you multiply the user supplied page size by 2?